# Something is eating the leaves on my pepper plants. Any idea what it could be?

Tags: leaves, peppers, pest-damage

Something is eating the leaves on my pepper plants. Any idea what it could be?
[image: Pepper plant leaves]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rounded edges of the eaten spots, it appears that you have slug issues. The rounded edges of the eaten areas are typical of slug damage - because slugs don't have teeth they kind of suck the leaf into their mouths. [Here's](https://urbanfarmcolorado.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/slug-damage.jpg) an example of another slug-eaten leaf.